# filtering rows which have highest consecutive values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe containing 3 million records. It has two columns, column A and column B which is the timestamp of data gathering. I am trying to split it into multiple dataframes according to the following conditions:

1. First, after grouping by Column A, any group with less than 3 members should be dropped.
2. Second, all records that have the same column A value and the count of records of column B, in which the timestamp was less than 7 seconds, is more than 4 should be saved as a CSV file.

```
Column A    Column B
  D            3
  A            2
  A            2 
  A            8
  A            13
  C            15
  D            8
  D            6
  F            3
  F            14
  F            2
  F            5
  F            2
  G            20
  B            12
  N            15
  N            1
  N            2
  N            1
  N            2
  N            3
```

I developed the following code that meets the first condition, but the second condition.

```
#Filtering records that their Column A's values repeated less than four times. 
grouped = df.groupby('A')
for i in grouped.groups.keys():
    p = grouped.get_group(i)
    if len(p.index)>3:
# Filtering records that their column B's values are less than 6        
        y= [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(p['Column B']<6) if k==True]
        if len(y) !=0: 
            if max(y)>4:
                p.to_csv('D:/TEST1/'f"{i}.csv", sep=';')
```

This code saves all column values that contain at least four consecutive values less than 6. It means it doesn't filter records whose values are more than 6. For example, in the proposed example, the only value that can be saved as a CSV file is 'N', but my code saves all values of N while I need to save only the last consecutive five values which are less than 6.

Comment: Your code does not match with your sample data. How can this work: `pd.to_datetime(p['Column A'].astype(str))`? Also, I'm having trouble understanding the first condition. Do you mean after grouping by Column A, any group with less than 3 members should be dropped?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I corrected the code, and I changed my description too.

Comment: Can you show your expected output for given sample input?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your example with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

columnA = ['D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'B', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N']
columnB = [3, 2, 2, 8, 13, 15, 8, 6, 3, 14, 2, 5, 2, 20, 12, 15, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = zip(columnA, columnB),
                  columns = ['columnA', 'columnB'])
```

> First, after grouping by Column A, any group with less than 3 members should be dropped.

The `group by` and `filter` function are clear and fast ways to do this task.

```
# any group with less than 3 members should be dropped
df1 = df.groupby('columnA').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)
print(df1)
```

[image: df1]

> Second, all records that have the same column A value and the count of records of column B, in which the timestamp was less than 7 seconds, is more than 4 should be saved as a CSV file.

This task was confusing, but my best interpretation of this was to keep all timestamps that were less than 7 (using the `where` function) and then only keep the rows that were part of a group of size more than 4.

My solution saves the new dataframe as floats for the timestamp column. I'm not sure why it did that, but it is an easy fix if you need to change that.

```
# keep rows with timestamp less than 7 and only keep rows that are a part of a group with more than 4 values
df2 = df1.where(df['columnB'] < 7).groupby('columnA').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 4)
print(df2)
```

[image: df2]

Finally, this saves the dataframe to the csv.

```
# save to csv
df2.to_csv("mycsv.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code saves all values less than 7 regardless of the second condition. For example, if "N" values were 4, 5, 10, 1, 2, 3 it saves 4, 5, 1, 2, 3. While I am striving to develop a code for consecutive values that counts were more than 3. In this case, it is expected to be 1, 2, 3.